# Extract substring in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I got a string like this:

```
string = "item=somevalue&user=user1";
```

And I need to find a way to extract, in Java, the substring "somevalue" (i.e. the substring after item= and before &).

Answer (score 3):

JUst use a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead assertions like below,

```
(?<=item=).*?(?=&)
```

**OR**

```
(?<=item=)[^&]*(?=&)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=item=)` string which preceeds the match must be `ietm=`
- `[^&]*` Match any character but not of `&` symbol zero or more times.
- `(?=&)` Character which follows the match must be `&` symbol.

**Code:**

```
String s = "item=somevalue&user=user1";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=item=).*?(?=&)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

**Output:**

```
somevalue
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
String test= "item=somevalue&user=user1";
String tok[]=test.split("&");
String finalTok[]=tok[0].split("=");
System.out.println(finalTok[1]);
```

**Output :**

```
somevalue
```

Comment: This asumes that the item value is in the first key/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "item=somevalue&user=user1";
        String result = "item=somevalue&user=user1".substring(str.indexOf("=") + 1, str.indexOf("&"));
        System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Output:**

**somevalue**

Answer (score 0):

One line solution!

```
System.out.println(string.substring(string.indexOf("=")+1, string.indexOf("&")));
```

Or

if in case 'somevalue' place is changed add following code!
`string = "user=user1&item=somevalue";` 
`System.out.println(string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("=")+1));`

Comment: Not if the string is `"user=user1&item=somevalue"`.

Comment: Please read the question once again. He/She mentioned in bracket '(i.e. the substring after item= and before &).' Means place of 'somevalue' is not going to change with respect to question.

Comment: He wrote "I got a string LIKE this". LIKE means it is an example. What is fix and what may change is not explained. It looks like a query part of an URL and so the order or number of parameters may vary.

Comment: Dude, According to a question it answered! If you want both value I can give them with one more extra line code. Thats all! No big deal!                                                                  For your doubt following is the solution.                                                            string = "user=user1&item=somevalue";
  System.out.println(string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("=")+1));

Comment: With this attitude the shortest solution would be `System.out.println("somevalue")`. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Haha. My simple solution is always better than a long code. Whatever is given in question, it will work for it definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting strings on special characters is an often required task and in my opinion regex is quite overkill and has bad performance for such a simple task. Everybody should have some performant string utils for often used task.

e.g. you can do this

```
for (String s : splitToIterable(str, '&')) {
    if (s.startsWith("item=")) {
        String itemValue = s.substring(5);
    }
}
```

if you have a helper method like this

```
public static Iterable<String> splitToIterable(final String str, final char delim) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return new Iterable<String>() {
        public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<String>() {
                int lastIndex = 0;
                String next = fetchNext();

                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return next != null;
                }

                public String next() {
                    if (next == null) {
                        throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    }
                    String result = next;
                    next = fetchNext();
                    return result;
                }

                public String fetchNext() {
                    if (lastIndex == -1) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    String next;
                    int i = str.indexOf(delim, lastIndex);
                    if (i > -1) {
                        next = str.substring(lastIndex, i);
                        lastIndex = i + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        next = str.substring(lastIndex);
                        lastIndex = -1;
                    }
                    return next;
                }

                public void remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```